# Ruby private attr_accessor and unexpected nil

Tags: ruby

Back when I used Ruby regularly, I had a bad habit of leaving everything public and ignoring privacy. Unfortunately, that ignorance is coming back to haunt me. Here's a simpler version of my problem:

```
class Something
    private
    attr_accessor :sneaky
    public

    def initialize
        @sneaky = 0
    end

    def test
        while sneaky < 10
            puts "#{sneaky}"
            sneaky = (sneaky + 1)
        end
    end
end

test = Something.new
test.test
```

This prints the correct value of sneaky (`0`), then errors out at `sneaky = (sneaky + 1)`, saying that `sneaky` is `nil`:

```
0
test.rb:13:in `test': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

What's up with that? `@sneaky`'s been set to 0 in the constructor. And if it really were nil, shouldn't that `puts` print a blank line and not a `0`?

EDIT: Yep, replacing `sneaky = (sneaky + 1)` with `self.sneaky = sneaky + 1` solves the problem, even though `self.sneaky=` looks like a privacy violation, since it has an explicit receiver. Apparently an exception is made for setters. But the weird interaction with privacy means you can't say `self.sneaky += 1` (you end up getting `test.rb:14:in 'test': private method 'sneaky' called for #<Something:0x000001019004c8 @sneaky=0> (NoMethodError)`). Fortunately I'm [not the only one who thinks that's weird](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A form of `foo = bar` assigns to a local variable called `foo`. If you want to call an `attr_writer`, you need to use an explicit receiver: `self.sneaky += 1`.

This has nothing to do with `private`, it's just basic Ruby syntax for local variable assignments.

Comment: `private` is relevant in that this is a private accessor and private methods generally cannot be called using an explicit receiver. For that reason, `self.sneaky += 1` doesn't work. But `self.sneaky = sneaky + 1` works, ugly as it looks. Thanks for pushing me to try ignoring the intuitive privacy rules, though!

Comment: Yes, this is an oversight in the Ruby Specification. I reported it 6 months ago, and it will maybe be included in Ruby 2.3, so that `self.sneaky += 1` works. I totally forgot that I am running a version of 2.2-trunk with the patch from the bugreport applied, so that I don't get an error.

Comment: Ah, I see you found my bugreport :-D